# How to stop user input to show on interactive terminal window?

Tags: bash, terminal, output, sh, user-input

Here is an example of script:

```
while true; do 
printf ""
done
```

Now if I run this script on a interactive terminal it obviously print nothing!

but in same case if I also start typing `CHARACTERS` and `KEYS` from my keyboard they will obviously show on terminal window while the script is running interactively.

Example output:

```
fasd^[[D^[[A^[[Cfsf
```

I want to temporarily stop user input to show while script is still running.

Thankyou, for any help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In my [piu-piu](https://github.com/vaniacer/piu-piu-SH) project I'm switching user input on and off like this:

```
...
COF='\e[?25l' #Cursor Off
CON='\e[?25h' #Cursor On

cursor () {
    case $1 in
         on) stty  echo; printf "$CON";;
        off) stty -echo; printf "$COF";;
    esac
}
...

cursor on
cursor off
...
```

Comment: Wow! Piu-Piu Game is Really awesome.